# How to reuse the output of an environment

Tags: environments, data-structures

I have created an environment with `\NewEnviron` that processes some input. For the sake of the discussion, it is something like

```
\NewEnviron{myworkingenvironment}[1]
{   
    \BODY % BODY is expected to define \A, \B and \C
    
    \numericResult{\A + \B + \C}
    \textResult{\A + \B + \C}
}
```

The functions typeset the output I want them to and I use the environment extensively (the parameter `#1`, thus far unused, should serve as an ID).

Now I want to use the variables of this environment in another one, like:

```
\NewEnviron{mynewenvironment}[1]
{   

    \BODY 
     
    The input was \get{#1:A}, \get{#1:B} and \get{#1:C}
    The result was \get{id:numericResult}.
}
```

How can I implement this `get` macro? The options I've found so far (e.g. change `\@currentlabelname` and defining a label afterwards) do not seem to work (I always get the name of the section where the reference is, instead of the value I expected).

Answer (score 2):

I *think* this does what you require.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{myworkingenvironment}[1]{\BODY%
\global\expandafter\let\csname#1A\endcsname\A
\global\expandafter\let\csname#1B\endcsname\B}

\NewEnviron{mynewenvironment}[1]{\BODY%
\def\getrelay##1:##2{\csname##1##2\endcsname}
\def\get##1{\getrelay##1}
\get{#1:A} is a friendly clown.
\get{ABC:B} is a dangerous doll.
}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{myworkingenvironment}{ABC}
\newcommand\A{Pennywise}
\newcommand\B{Chucky}
\end{myworkingenvironment}

\begin{mynewenvironment}{ABC}
\end{mynewenvironment}

\end{document}
```

The idea is that when you create a `myworkingenvironment` called `ABC`, global macros called `\ABCA` and `\ABCB` are generated automatically. The `\get` command implemented here just allows you to say something like `\get{#1:A}` (where `#1` is `ABC`) rather than typing `\ABCA` directly. Let me know if this works for you, and I will add a more detailed explanation.